# Auto Increment Column value whenever update happen on that row in sql server

Tags: sql, triggers

I want to maintain a column which will store that how many times a row has been modified.
So whenever the row has been updated I want to increase the column value.
I think I have to use trigger for that.But I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: why is trigger not cool to you?

Comment: I just that I don't want to use trigger in this case.

Comment: I think you should get your job done by the solution that is made for such cases, and triggers are for your case. Test my trigger, it works and there is no harm to your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO trigger is the way to go, but if you sure that you control all your updates, then you can  do as simple as this:

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET somefield='newvalue', 
       update_count = update_count+1 
   WHERE id=n
```

Comment: really cool answer.Thanks.Why do I have not think like this before.

Comment: @VimalPatel remember this works only if you update your row just from this code, so if your data gets changed from some other place, say stored procedure that doesn't implement this update, your count column doesn't update.

Comment: Sorry @peterm for a second I thought your code is wrong, then I read it again. Here is an upvote :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER CountRows 
    ON TestCount 
    after Update
AS 
Update TestCount  set Cnt = Cnt +1 where ID in (select ID from inserted)
GO
```

whenever some value in a row changes, the grigger adds +1 to the same row's Cnt column value.